# In Erlang, is it possible to send a running process to a different node?

Tags: erlang, actor, agent, mobility

I have been researching Mobile Agents, and was wondering if it is possible to send a running process to another node in erlang.  I know it is possible to send a process on another node a message. I know it is possible to load a module on all nodes in a cluster.  Is it possible to move a process that might be in some state on a particular node to another node and resume it's state.  That is, does erlang provide strong mobility? Or is it possible to provide strong mobility in erlang?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but there is no "Move process to node" call. However, if the process is built with a feature for migration, you can certainly do it by sending the function of the process and its state to another node and arrange for a spawn there. To get the identity of the process right, you will need to use either the global process registry or gproc, as the process will change *pid*.

There are other considerations as well: The process might be using an ETS table whose data are not present on the other node, or it may have stored stuff in the process dictionary (state from the random module comes to mind).

---

The general consensus in Erlang is that processes are not mobilized to move between machines. Rather, one either arranges for a *takeover* of applications between nodes should a node die. Or for distribution of the system so data are already distributed to another machine. In any case, the main problem of making state persistent in the event of errors still hold, mobility or not - and distribution is a nice tool to solve the persistence problem.